# Different kinds of load-balacing policies

Tags: load-balancing

I'm doing an internship where I have to dynamically scale an application according to the workload. Right now, I use a very basic policy : if the average CPU of my nodes is above 60%, I add a new node, if it goes under 20% I remove a node. I was wondering if there was other types of scaling policies that I'm not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: You could also add a time threshold for how long the average CPU load remains at 60 or 20, to avoid spikes causing more nodes to start up, or a node to drop too early.  You may also consider memory, or queries-per-second as a metric for scaling, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on the different aspects on how the load-balancing could be achieved. You can refer to my blog where things are mentioned more appropriately. Link : www.loadbalancerweb.wordpress.com